# switch fragment code to activity code

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

hi i am begineer on android ,i have an app that contains a history fragment I am trying to convert my Fragment Code to Activity code !(i want to start this  activity after  button click) but i don't know how to do that so please help me

here's my fragment :

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment implements MainActivity.FragmentRefresh {

    ImageView ivSettings;
    private FragmentActivity mContext;
    private RecyclerView rvInsta;

    //DB
    private DBController dbcon;
    private ImageRecyclerAdaptor imageRecyclerAdaptor;

    public static HistoryFragment newInstance() {
        //Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putString(ARG_PAGE, title);
        HistoryFragment fragment = new HistoryFragment();
        //fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        //fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Tag1","MoviesFrag");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        mContext =getActivity();
        //DB
        dbcon = new DBController(mContext);

        rvInsta= (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvInstaImages);
        imageRecyclerAdaptor = new ImageRecyclerAdaptor(mContext);
        rvInsta.setAdapter(imageRecyclerAdaptor);
        rvInsta.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));

        rvInsta.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvInsta.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
        rvInsta.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        rvInsta.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        //rvInsta.s/

        imageRecyclerAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override public void refresh() {
        if (imageRecyclerAdaptor!=null) {
            imageRecyclerAdaptor.onRefreshh();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentRefresh{
ImageView ivSettings;
private RecyclerView rvInsta;

//DB
private DBController dbcon;
private ImageRecyclerAdaptor imageRecyclerAdaptor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_history);

    dbcon = new DBController(this);

    rvInsta= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvInstaImages);
    imageRecyclerAdaptor = new ImageRecyclerAdaptor(this);
    rvInsta.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    rvInsta.setAdapter(imageRecyclerAdaptor);


    rvInsta.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rvInsta.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    rvInsta.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    rvInsta.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    imageRecyclerAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override public void refresh() {
    if (imageRecyclerAdaptor!= null) {
        imageRecyclerAdaptor.onRefreshh();
    }
}
```

}